# plug-in com.ibm.ws.execute.iscdeploy not found when attempting to install WebSphere Application Server

Tags: linux, centos, ibm, websphere

On a clean install of CentOS 7, I have installed IBM Installation Manager. I downloaded version 9.0.0.6 of WebSphere Application Server from IBM Fix Central, and unzipped the installation files to the /tmp/was directory.

```
unzip 9.0.0-WS-WAS-FP006.zip /tmp/was
```

The listAvailablePackages command shows that the BASE offering is available.

```
./imcl listAvailablePackages -repositories /tmp/was/
com.ibm.websphere.BASE.v90_9.0.6.20171205_1311
```

When I attempt to install the BASE offering, I get the following:

```
./imcl install com.ibm.websphere.BASE.v90_9.0.6.20171205_1311 -repositories /tmp/was/
ERROR: 'plug-in com.ibm.ws.execute.iscdeploy.v85_8.5.5001.20130515_0000' not found in /tmp/was
ERROR: 'plug-in com.ibm.was.base.moreinfo.v90_9.0.0.20160412_0000' not found in /tmp/was
```

I have verified that the iscdeploy and moreinfo plug-in's are indeed not found in /tmp/was. I am not sure what needs to be done to be able to install the BASE offering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSphere Application Server fixpacks are cumulative, ie. 9006 contains all the fixes of 9005 and all previous fixpacks, but they are not full installation packages, see the prereq section of the 9006 fixpack on FixCentral where it states:

> Prerequisites
>       Version 9.0 offering must be installed prior to installation of Fix Pack 9.0.0.6.

The error you're getting seems to imply imcl isn't finding a BASE installation, you'll need to obtain the 9.0.0.0 GA (general availability) release and install it first, then apply the 9006 fixpack.
If it's not the case, your imcl commandline should have a parameter

```
-installationDirectory product_installation_location
```

that points to your existing WAS BASE 900 installation.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't certain if I had to install the BASE install. I'll go ahead and install the BASE and then install the Fix Pack.